# Using own quote environment use more width than it should

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I created my own envorinment for placing quotes or something important in my text. (it is simply a \node inside tikz)
However, when I set the \textwidth of the nodeto \linewidth and set an inner sep the right border is outside my margins. 
When I use a smaller textwidth like .9\linewidth it seems to be okay. Smaller textwidths also work. I want that the border are excatly at the linewidth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\NewEnviron{bquote}{%
\par%
\vspace{.5cm}
\noindent% 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=justify}]%   %%Linewidth default bei 7pt
\node[text width=.7\linewidth,font=\normalsize, scale=1, draw=none,inner sep=20](q){\BODY};%
\draw[fill=red] (q.center) circle (1cm) node {OKAY};
\draw[semithick,line width=.4pt,overlay,black] ($(q.north west) + (15pt,0)$)--(q.north west)--(q.south west)-- ($(q.south west) + (15pt,0)$);%
\draw[semithick, line width=.4pt,overlay,black] ($(q.north east) - (15pt,0)$) --(q.north east)  -- (q.south east)--($(q.south east)- (15pt,0)$) ;% 
\end{tikzpicture}%
\par%
\vspace{.35cm}
}%
\title{ForumMWE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{bquote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{bquote}
\noindent\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

This result in:

[image]

Changing this

```
\node[text width=.7\linewidth,font=\normalsize, scale=1, draw=none,inner sep=20](q){\BODY};%
```

to this

```
\node[text width=1\linewidth,font=\normalsize, scale=1, draw=none,inner sep=20](q){\BODY};%
```

result in:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compute the line width so to remove the space for the braces:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewEnviron{bquote}{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,every node/.style={align=justify}]%   %%Linewidth default bei 7pt
  \node[
    text width=\linewidth-40pt,
    font=\normalsize,
    scale=1,
    draw=none,
    inner sep=20
  ](q){\BODY};
  \draw[fill=red] (q.center) circle (1cm) node {OKAY};
  \draw[semithick,line width=.4pt,overlay,black]
    ($(q.north west) + (15pt,0)$)--(q.north west)--(q.south west)
     -- ($(q.south west) + (15pt,0)$);
  \draw[semithick, line width=.4pt,overlay,black]
    ($(q.north east) - (15pt,0)$) --(q.north east)  -- (q.south east)
     --($(q.south east)- (15pt,0)$) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\title{ForumMWE}
\author{SRel}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{bquote}
\lipsum[4]
\end{bquote}
\noindent\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is `text width=\linewidth-40` not enough ?

Comment: @nidhin Apparently it is. `;-)`